# Centering in CSS grid with a fixed width column

Tags: html, css, css-grid, centering

Im trying to make a simple CSS centered grid layout.
I know that when I use `justify-items: center`, the items inside a grid container are supposed to align horizontally, but when I specify a column width in pixels like this `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px)` the whole grid return to normal. So is there any way to make the grid items centered but in same time specify the column width in pixels?
Here are my example:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
```

```
.container {
    background-color: #aa96da;
    display: grid;
    justify-items: center;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);

    /*Only if I change this 100px to '1fr' the justify-items will work */
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
}

.item {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: how you want to center an item with width=100px inside a column with the same width? there is no room for centring

Comment: What I want is to center the whole grid container inside the body not the item inside the particular grid

Answer (score 5):

Change the `justify-items` to `justify-content` and it should work.

```css
.container {
    background-color: #aa96da;
    display: grid;
    /* justify-items: center; */
    justify-content: center;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);

    /*Only if I change this 100px to '1fr' the justify-items will work */
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,  100px);
}

.item {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**: You want `justify-content` not `justify-items`

```css
.container {
  background-color: #aa96da;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center; /* -items to -content */
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  /*Only if I change this 100px to '1fr' the justify-items will work */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Long answer:**

There's a difference between the grid item and the space it lives in.

When you define a grid, you're only defining rows/columns of the grid called `tracks`, Not actually defining where each element goes etc.

The DOM elements only follow the flow of the grid and are placed accordingly, which we can alter using properties like `grid-column` `grid-row`

You can look at it like this:
[image]

As you can see there's `The Grid container`, `The Grid`, `The Columns`, `The Rows` and then `The Grid items`.

The Grid items lives in the intersection between the two called `The Grid Area` (this what makes css grid better than flexbox in some ways)

And `justify-items` aligns the grid items within that area.

---

So `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);`  This means 3 columns their width is the width of the grid split evenly between them.

**Demo**

*Don't look at the code just the preview*

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

[grid] {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

[column] {
  flex: 1 0 calc(100% / 3);
  border: 2px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  
}

[column]>div {
  width: 100px;
  flex:1;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div grid>
  <div column>
    <div>Grid Item</div>
  </div>
  <div column>
    <div>Grid Item</div>
  </div>
  <div column>
    <div>Grid Item</div>
  </div>
  <div column>
    <div>Grid Item</div>
  </div>
  <div column>
    <div>Grid Item</div>
  </div>
  <div column>
    <div>Grid Item</div>
  </div>
  <div column>
    <div>Grid Item</div>
  </div>
  <div column>
    <div>Grid Item</div>
  </div>
  <div column>
    <div>Grid Item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the grid columns are wider than the grid items `100px` which means there space to center stuff, So `justify-items: center;` will center them inside.

That's why it looks like the grid is centered, But it's actually not reasons why changing to `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);` breaks it.

---

In the case of `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);`

**Demo**

*Don't look at the code just the preview*

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

[ctr] {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

[grid] {
  height: 300px;
  width: 340px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

[column] {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  border: 2px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

[column]>div {
  width: 100px;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div ctr>
  <div grid>
    <div column>
      <div>Grid Item</div>
    </div>
    <div column>
      <div>Grid Item</div>
    </div>
    <div column>
      <div>Grid Item</div>
    </div>
    <div column>
      <div>Grid Item</div>
    </div>
    <div column>
      <div>Grid Item</div>
    </div>
    <div column>
      <div>Grid Item</div>
    </div>
    <div column>
      <div>Grid Item</div>
    </div>
    <div column>
      <div>Grid Item</div>
    </div>
    <div column>
      <div>Grid Item</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the columns width equal the grid item's so they all fit snugly within the columns and the grid is still empty.

Comment: Oh, thanks that totally fixed it ! Also after rereading your answer two times, I finally get how the grid layout works and what `justify-items` and `justify-content` means.

Comment: @Adolin If you want a more in-depth explanation [**Box alignment in grid layout**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Alignment/Box_Alignment_In_Grid_Layout)

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the flex property on top of those grid elements and then center it with `justify-content:center;`

- index.html:

```
<div class="centering_items">
       <div class="container">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

- style.css

```css
.centering_items {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.container {
    background-color: #aa96da;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);

    /*Only if I change this 100px to '1fr' the justify-items will work */
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,  100px);
}

.item {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
```